# jQuery .toggleClass not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

file name is index.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div").hover(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("multi")
    }
}
```

file name is stylesheet.css

```
    a{
text-decoration:none;
color:green;
}
a:hover{
text-decoration:none;
color:blue;
}
a:visited{
text-decoration:none;
color:green;
background-color:red;
}
div{
font-family:Garamond;
border:3px solid blue;
width:75px;
height:45px;
margin:3px;
a:nth-child(5) div{
border-color:red;
}
.multi{
border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #ff0000, #00ff00 50%, #0000ff 75%)1%;
border-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #ff0000, #00ff00 50%, #0000ff 75%)1%;
border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #ff0000, #00ff00 50%, #0000ff 75%)1%;
width:120px
}
```

file name is index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='index.js'></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
<a href="http://www.criticalsoftware.com/en/homepage"><img src="http://tse3.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.M6306c8d673012b728da1d23d43adbcdfo0&w=134&h=135&c=7&rs=1&qlt=90&o=4&pid=1.1"/></a>
</head>
<body>
<a href="day1.html"><div><h1>day 1</h1></div></a>
<a href="day2.html"><div><h1>day 2</h1></div></a>
<a href="day3.html"><div><h1>day 3</h1></div></a>
<a href="day4.html"><div><h1>day 4</h1></div></a>
<a href="finalday.html"class=""><div><h1>final day</h1></div></a>
```

The jQuery is having no effect on the resulting page. I have included all css that could effect the div. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle that reproduces the issue?

Comment: You have some syntax errors in your CSS and JS - missing closing brackets and braces. Fix those and you get this: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/4nnntp35/. Also note that JS is not required here, as you can use the `:hover` CSS selector to achieve this

Comment: Did you include jQuery in your HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $("div").hover(function (){
        $(this).addClass("multi");
    }, function (){     
        $(this).removeClass("multi");   
    });
});
```

```css
a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:green;
}
a:hover{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:blue;
}
a:visited{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:green;
  background-color:red;
}
div{
  font-family:Garamond;
  border:3px solid blue;
  width:120px;
  height:45px;
  margin:3px;
}
h1{
  margin:0px;
}
a:nth-child(5) div{
  border-color:red;
}
.multi{
  border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #ff0000, #00ff00 50%, #0000ff 75%)1%;
  border-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #ff0000, #00ff00 50%, #0000ff 75%)1%;
  border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #ff0000, #00ff00 50%, #0000ff 75%)1%;
  width:200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="day1.html"><div><h1>day 1</h1></div></a>
<a href="day2.html"><div><h1>day 2</h1></div></a>
<a href="day3.html"><div><h1>day 3</h1></div></a>
<a href="day4.html"><div><h1>day 4</h1></div></a>
<a href="finalday.html"class=""><div><h1>final day</h1></div></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error near closing `document.read`y and `.hover()` events:

In css also you need to check all closing braces:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div").hover(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("multi");
     }); // close braces like this
}); // close braces like this
```

```css
a{
text-decoration:none;
color:green;
}
a:hover{
text-decoration:none;
color:blue;
}
a:visited{
text-decoration:none;
color:green;
background-color:red;
}
div{
font-family:Garamond;
border:3px solid blue;
width:120px;
height:45px;
margin:3px;
  } /* Add here closing bracket*/
h1{
margin:0px;
}
a:nth-child(5) div{
border-color:red;
}
.multi{
border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #ff0000, #00ff00 50%, #0000ff 75%)1%;
border-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #ff0000, #00ff00 50%, #0000ff 75%)1%;
border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #ff0000, #00ff00 50%, #0000ff 75%)1%;
width:200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="day1.html"><div><h1>day 1</h1></div></a>
<a href="day2.html"><div><h1>day 2</h1></div></a>
<a href="day3.html"><div><h1>day 3</h1></div></a>
<a href="day4.html"><div><h1>day 4</h1></div></a>
<a href="finalday.html"class=""><div><h1>final day</h1></div></a>
```

Comment: You missed the one on the `hover()` function, and the CSS has problems too.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes closing brace was missing too in css